# Edit in Place Directive with Button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am implementing an edit-in-place functionality where the fields become editable after the user clicks a button.  Here are the two directives:

Directive for button:

```
.directive('editbutton', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       template: '<div ng-hide="editorEnabled>' +
          '<button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="enableEditor(item)">' +
             '<i class="icon-edit"></i>' +
          '</button>' +
        '</div>' +
    '<div ng-show="editorEnabled>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="save(item)">' +
        '<i class="icon-ok"></i>' +
      '</button>' +
    '</div>',
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
  console.log("butotn");

  scope.editorEnabled = false;

  scope.enableEditor = function(item){
    scope.editorEnabled = true;
  }

  scope.disableEditor = function(){
    scope.editorEnabled = false;
  }

  scope.save = function(){
    // edit client side and server side
    scope.disableEditor();
  }

}
};
});
```

For the text edit in place:

```
angular.module('solarquote.directives', []).directive('editfield', function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
   //scope: { value:"=editfield", inherit:'@editorEnabled'},
   transclude: true,
   template: '<span ng-hide="editorEnabled" ng-transclude></span>' +   // viewable field
     '<span ng-show="editorEnabled"><input class="input-medium" ng-model="value"></span>', // editable field
   link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
       // nothing here
   }
};
})
```

And the HTML:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td>
    <a href="" ng-click="filter_fund(item)">
      <span editfield="item.fields.name">{{ item.fields.name }}</span>
    </a>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span editfield="item.fields.address">{{ item.fields.address }}</span>
  </td>

  <td style="text-align:center" ng-show="editable_table"><span editbutton></span></td>
```

The problem is that the editorEnabled scope cannot be accessed when I implement my own scope to retrieve the names. I have tried using @ and = to grab the "inherited" scope but cannot figure out how.

The objective is to prepopulate the input field using =editfield. Then have the editorEnabled scope shared with the button that enables and disables it. However, the scope does not have an editor Enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this tutorial that goes over directive to directive communication. There are also other tutorials related to directives which I found to be very informative. http://www.egghead.io/video/rzMrBIVuxgM

Answer (score 1):

There are two keypoints to get it working:

1. dealing with **isolated scope** directive - you must pass all required
   data via attributes. In you example it should be `editfield` and
   `editorEnabled`. E.g.:

   ```html
   <span editfield="item.fields.name" editor-enabled="editorEnabled">
   ```

   and in directive:

   ```
   scope: { value:"=editfield", editorEnabled: '='},
   ```
2. when passing data to directive **don't use camelCase in attribute names**!

   *This will not work*:

   ```html
   <span editfield="user.name" editorEnabled="editorEnabled">
   ```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLQH3/1/

Also you may checkout [angular-xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#text-btn) library that does exactly your task without writing own custom directives.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I don't know if you need to write a custom directive for this.

If I were you I would have [ng-disabled](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) on my input field, something like:

```
<button ng-model="clicked"></button>
<input ng-disabled="clicked"/>
```

The following would enable/disable (make it editable/uneditable) the input field whenever the button is clicked.